# PHP: socket listen problem

Tags: php, sockets

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$host = "127.0.0.1";
$portListen = 1234;
$portSend = 1240;


// create socket
$sSender = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

socket_connect($sSender, $host, $portListen);

socket_write($sSender, "test", strlen ("test"));


$sListen = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_set_option($sListen, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

socket_bind($sListen, $host, $portSend);

socket_listen($sListen,1);
$dataSock = socket_accept($sListen);
echo socket_read($dataSock, 3, PHP_NORMAL_READ);

// close sockets
socket_close($sSender);
socket_close($sListen);
?>
```

I send "test" to another application, it receives, and send back "ack". Problem is, I can only do it once. If I refresh, I get the address is already used error. I tried the solutions suggested on [php.net](http://my.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-close.php) but to no avail. Trying to socket_shutdown() before socket_close() only give me not connected warning, and upon refreshing will give me a never ending loading.

From what I understand the reason socket is not immediately closed is because there is still data in the buffer. But as you can see I explicitly state to listen to only 1 connection. Plus I am only sending 3 characters from my application and reading 3 in this script.

What am I doing wrong?

edit: The reason I'm using 2 sockets is because I cannot listen() after write() which give me socket is already connected error. Skipping listen() and going straight for read() after write() give me invalid argument error.

Comment: Found a much easier way to perform this. Check out this blog post. http://www.christophh.net/2012/07/24/php-socket-programming/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see, after having a few hours sleep and re-analyzing my code and the documentations, I managed to fix everything. You guys are right, 1 socket is indeed enough and the correct way:

```
<?php

$host = "127.0.0.1";
$portListen = 1234;
$sSender = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");

socket_connect($sSender, $host, $portListen) or die("Could not connect\n");

socket_write($sSender, "test", strlen ("test")) or die("Could not write output\n");

echo socket_read($sSender, 3, PHP_NORMAL_READ);

socket_close($sSender);
?>
```

So simple!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to create 2 sockets for read and write? It looks like an odd design. Client apps usually open a socket connection to the server, then send a request and read the server's response on the same socket.
Also, creating a listening socket (iow a server) won't scale past any firewall or NAT gateway.

Answer to yor comment: No need to listen. just read (possibly blocking operation if your server hasn't replied yet).

Comment: I thought that's the correct design. I cannot seem to socket_listen with the first socket... I get: Warning: socket_listen() [function.socket-listen]: unable to listen on socket [0]: A connect request was made on an already connected socket. in C:\wamp\www\sock.php on line 22

Answer (score 1):

After a connection is closed, the socket enters a linger state so that if (during the close) packets were lost and retransmitted, the response would be a clean acknowledgement instead of `RST` (reset) indicating no such socket was open.  It's part of the TCP specification, you can't make it stop happening.

`Listen(1)` doesn't mean accept only one connection, it means maintain a queue of up 1 connections waiting for an application to `accept()` them.  So as soon as you accept the first, the socket is ready to listen for more.

Like everybody else, I'm wondering why the odd design, but I assume it's a boiled-down example that presents your problem and doesn't necessarily present your real plan.